# Formula Limits in Visual Force

Tags: visualforce, formula

I thought it would be easier to find the answer to those but do Visual Force formulas have the 5000 byte compile limit? I have formulas that are based on lookups that are based on lookups.  I can make them work in Process Builder or with a Flow but I would rather not have to trigger an edit to call the formula.

Is Visual Force a good idea for this or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: What do you mean by "those visualforce formulas"? Do you mean the merge expression syntax `{!something.field1__c + something.field2__c}`? Giving an example would probably help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, they're "expressions," not "formulas," but they do use a similar syntax. As long as you're not using `apex:form`, expressions in a Visualforce page can be as complicated as allowed by the maximum execution time. If you use `apex:form`, then your expressions will eventually fill up the View State, which is limited to 135k, but it's not a linear growth, either. If all you want to do is display information when you load a record, Visualforce is a decent alternative to Process Builder, etc.

Comment: In a few rare cases I have had a too-complicated declarative formula in VF. One way to piece that out is to save one portion of the calculation in an `apex:variable` and then reference it in the formula. This comes with the proviso that `apex:variable` names can cause trouble if they collide with the same name used in any Visualforce page/component/controller in the same Apex transaction.